# How to reduce leaking at plastic click-on 2-way coupling?

Tags: hose

How can I reduce the leaking seen here?
[image]
It is leaking at the standard single o-ring hose connector 2-way plastic click-on connector such as [this](https://www.hillsirrigation.com.au/shop/irrigation/home-garden/garden-tap-hose-fittings/12mm-plastic-2-end-hose-coupler/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwuaiXBhCCARIsAKZLt3niEAaSiA6OIml6rJHiKRCab8mXNezBlWm1FH-xSgf2HQJK5Q5r1T4aAocuEALw_wcB) that came with the kit.

The water pressure is already at the minimum to drive the drippers, as seen [here](https://youtube.com/shorts/wim6ITwOBog).

Comment: That is a quick connect coupling, spring loaded. Push it forward so the o-ring sits in the groove, and if it does not stop get a new one

Comment: They are cheap plastic, if pushing it on better does not work, just replace.  Usually comes with both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a quick connect coupling, spring loaded. Push it forward so the o-ring sits in the groove, and if it does not stop get a new one.

The orange part should be all the way forward (to the right) as far it goes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped to swap the connector but only if I also apply a good deal of pressure (https://youtube.com/shorts/EynZye5yJmo) and keep the connection totally straight. It seems I need some sort of clamp to maintain the pressure for the tight connection - what sort of clamp is used for this?

Comment: If both parts of the connector are in good shape, and the O-rings not damaged, the connection will not leak and an external clamp not be necessary.

Comment: There is a spring inside that should push it, yours might be stuck. Those do not need a clamp. Open it and make sure noting is stuck inside.

Comment: just a theroy, who ever installed the right part damaged it with players ?

Comment: Thanks, using a new spring-loaded quick connect coupling (orange piece) helped me get a stronger "click" connection, and now no leak.

Comment: @AlexHolcombe happy for you, thanks for the up-vote

Answer (score 4):

It's not on all the way. push it all the way on, push the black part while pulling the orange part

[image]

If it still leaks replace the rubber o-ring on the stationary pipe part,

[image]

I think what may have happened is that the O ring has cracked and fallen off, and the locking barbs on the hose end have caught in the now-empty O-ring groove, instead of catching on the locking flange.